# Set LESS font variable using multiple font fields

Tags: css, fonts, less, google-font-api

I have a list of fonts that I'm pulling in from Google's CDN. They list documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Subsets) but I'm having issues setting up the semibold italic styles. Is there a way to make this work?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,600italic,400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

```
@semibold: "Open Sans:600", sans-serif;
@semibold-italic: "Open Sans:600italic", sans-serif;
@light: "Open Sans:300", sans-serif;
```

I know that I can set the `font-weight` and style in `font-face`.

How can I include everything in my variable declaration?

Comment: Mixin is your best choice. Answer by @user3822179 sums up what must be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with how Google Fonts works, but maybe a mixin would be a decent alternative for you.

```
.semibold {
    font-family: 'Font', 'Font B', 'Font C';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

div {
    .semibold;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature). You can declare a style, say `.font`, which accept several parameters — in this case, it should accept `font-family`, `font-weight` and `font-style`. Of course you are free to add/remove other `font-` or `text-` related properties for further fine-tuning.

```
// Declare mixin
.font(@fontFamily: Arial, sans-serif; @fontWeight: normal; @fontStyle: normal) {
    font-family: @fontFamily;
    font-style: @fontStyle;
    font-weight: @fontWeight;
}

// Sample styles
.semibold {
    .font("Open Sans", sans-serif; 600; normal);
}
.semibold-italic {
    .font("Open Sans", sans-serif; 600; italic);
}
.light {
    .font("Open Sans", sans-serif; 300; normal);
}
```